# Java: How do I restart my program from the beginning?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class bot {
    private static Robot robot = null;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws AWTException, 
     InterruptedException {
        try {
            robot =new Robot ();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
        click ( 400,1000);

    }

    public static void click(int x, int y) throws AWTException, 
        InterruptedException{
        robot.mouseMove(x,y);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_I);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
}
```

I wrote this as a joke for a discord server I am in but I don't know how to make it restart or repeat the process.

I want it to start from the beginning and type out my sentence all over again. I am really new to Java so any help would be appreciated! Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Have a look at loops in Java [Java - Loop Control](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need is a loop.Try a following code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws AWTException,
        InterruptedException {
    try {
        robot =new Robot ();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

    while(true){
        click ( 400,1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked just like I needed it too! But why does that repeat everything? How does the loop work and why?

Comment: @CaydenHumphreys This will keep on running the click code until the while evaluation criteria is not met. So it will continue running until true is not true anymore.

I would suggest building in an exit criteria. For example if you press "X" on the keyboard a boolean value will be set to false which should stop the program.